# PyCharm: How to configure the interpreter chooser to start at ~/miniconda3/envs?

Tags: python, pycharm

Can I configure PyCharm in such a way that when I am prompted to choose an interpreter (when creating a new project, for example) the interpreter chooser begins at a specified directory, such as `~/miniconda3/envs` in my case?

Comment: which option you want to use after you click on new project, "New environment using" or  "Existing interpreter"

Comment: Either one, I guess. Typically it's a new environment, in that I'm telling it to use a new conda environment that I've recently created. I always create conda environments and they're always under `~/miniconda3/envs`, so it seems logical for the selector to start from there rather than me having to click through a few directory levels to get there. It's only saving me a few clicks, but my cognitive power is limited and I'm trying to conserve.  ;)

Comment: Try this, click on 'file' -> 'settings' -> type 'interpreter' in search box and you will see 'Project Interpreter'. Then on the right hand side you will see a tab where path of python.exe is specified. To the right of it, there is a small 'settings' icon. Click on it, then 'show all'. There you should see a default Python interpreter. click on that entry, then on from the right side, click 'edit', 3rd option vertically. Then change the path to the python exe of your conda environment. click ok  and apply. I hope this solves your problem.